# import TIME_ZONE from '@salesforce/i18n/timeZone'; Which Timezone does it returns? Browser timzone or Salesforce User Record Timezone

Tags: lightning-web-components, timezone

I was working on a requirement where I have to show DateTime in your time zone based on timezone setup in user record.

I am using `import TIME_ZONE from '@salesforce/i18n/timeZone';` to get the user timezone.

and then formatting the date using below piece of code:-

```
new Date(anydate).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
                        year: 'numeric',
                        month: '2-digit',
                        day: '2-digit',
                        timeZone: TIME_ZONE
                    });
```

Consider now there are two user. One sitting in INDIA and another one in US.

For the same record, The Dates displayed are different on UI for both user. I am expecting both to be same as both the user has same timezone setup in the user record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The i18n [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-i18n.html) explains that there are two different behaviours depending on the context of use:

> For LWR sites, the `lang` and `locale` are mapped to the language configured for the site, and `timeZone` is determined by the browser’s timezone rather than the user’s personal settings.

That can therefore be interpreted as for anything other than an LWR digital experience site, i.e. in the Salesforce UI and in Aura-based digital experience sites, the `timeZone` originates from the user's personal settings (so the time zone assigned to the User record).

Comment: Thanks Phil, Is the behaviour same in both LWR and Traditional Experience Portal?

Comment: I am assuming by "Traditional Experience Portal" you mean a site.com site rather than a Digital Experience? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes I meant Digital Experience. i Fixed it using Apex. Javascript was not giving me right result.

Comment: So for a Digital Experience I'd expect this to be the user's "personal settings". Are you saying it was not?